# Not able to parse this json

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse the json output from

> http://www.nyc.gov/portal/apps/311_contentapi/services/all.json

And my php `json_decode` returns a `NULL`

I am not sure where the issue is, I tried running a small subset of the data through JSONLint and it validated the json.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please copy the content here, your question should be self contained, and not require answerers to navigate to another page, and definitely not another site.

Comment: Sorry, It was more than 2000 lines, didnt want to paste it here.

Comment: Then you should fabricate or extract a relevant and small portion that still illustrates your problem and post that, instead.

Comment: It simply was not possible here. Not going against rules, just trying to solve something. @PaulPRO caught the error.

Comment: @looneydoodle: It absolutely _was_ possible. The very first thing you should have done in your prior debugging should have been to narrow down the issue to one or _maybe_ two lines of JSON. You just couldn't be bothered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in this section:

```
{
    "id":"2002-12-05-22-24-56_000010083df0188b4001eb56",
    "service_name":"Outdoor Electric System Complaint",
    "expiration":"2099-12-31T00:00:00Z",
    "brief_description":"Report faulty Con Edison equipment, including dangling or corroded power lines or "hot spots.""
}
```

See where it says "hot spots." in an already quoted string. Those `"`'s should've been escaped. Since you don't have access to edit the JSON perhaps you could do a search for `"hot spots.""` and replace it with `\"hot spots.\""` like `str_replace('"hot spots.""', '\\"hot spots.\\""\, $str);` for as long as that's in there. Of course that only helps if this is a one time thing. If the site continues to make errors in their JSON output you'll have to come up with something more complex.

Comment: Thanks! Is there some function I can run to take care of this? - I know this might be a dumb qn, but its NYC's website (Cant really get them to do anything right)

Comment: Right, gotcha. I am going to try and talk to the developers at nyc.gov

Comment: @looneydoodle Actually looking at the JSON the have the same error in other places too: `"Water Rate Structure Study.""`

Comment: Yeah, thats what I am looking at as well. I getting in touch with the developers now.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to identify the errors in the JSON ...

Since faulty quoting is the first thing to look for, I downloaded the JSON to a text file, opened in a text editor (I used vim but any full featured editor would do), ran a search and replace that removed all characters except double-quote and looked at the result.  It was clear that correct lines should have 4 double-quotes so I simply searched for 5 double-quotes together and found the first bad line.  I noted the line number and then undid the search and replace to get the original file back and looked at that line.  This gives you what you need to get the developers of the API to fix the JSON.

Writing code to automatically fix the bad JSON before giving it to `json_decode()` would be quite a bit harder but doable using techniques like those in another answer.

Comment: Thanks for that! I just finally managed to get in touch with the developers and I am waiting on them for a reply.

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHP manual:

> In the event of a failure to decode, json_last_error() can be used to determine the exact nature of the error.

Try calling it to see where the error is.

Comment: But the function only returns an error id, is there a reference for the errors?

Comment: Check the documentation: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php
It describes what are the possible return values.

Comment: Thanks! Going through it now. @PaulPRO found the issue